# How to reset ESP32 after a certain duration?

Tags: esp32, millis

I would like to reset my ESP32 from the software, how do I do it and how to make it do this at regular intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```cpp
uint32_t resetAfterMillis = 30000; // Reset after 30 seconds.
uint32_t lastResetWas;

void setup() {
   lastResetWas = millis();
}


void loop() {
  uint32_t now = millis();
  if (now >= lastResetWas + resetAfterMillis) 
  {
      lastResetWas = now;

      // Whatever you want to do here
      ESP.restart();

  }

}
```